# Posting TinyGPS++ co-ordinates as paramaters with GPRS

Tags: http, convert

I'm able to view my co-ords on the Serial Monitor using `Serial.println(gps.location.lat(), 6);`

I believe the data type returned by `gps.location.lat()` is double. I need to pass this value to a webservice with AT commands over GPRS.

`double latitude = gps.location.lat()`

Later in my code I execute AT commands to begin HTTP POST. I would like to know how to pass these double values in my paramaters.

`gsm.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://webservice/service1\"");
 gsm.println("AT+HTTPDATA=192,10000");
 gsm.println("latitude=" + latitude);` < This is not allowed.

How can I pass this parameter to my web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution may be to split the commands:

```
gsm.print("latitude=");
gsm.println(latitude);
```

I'm not sure how you should pass multiple parameters; if it is the usual syntax you can write something like

```
gsm.print("latitude=");
gsm.print(latitude);
gsm.print("&longitude=");
gsm.println("longitude);
```

If I have the time I'll research into this a bit.

To check what is the problem, you may try to send "static" messages, like

```
gsm.println("latitude=12.345");
```

To check if this format is the correct one

EDIT: after a very quick research

It looks like the AT commands are a bit more complicated. In order to send the parameters, at least on a SIM800L, you should:

- send the HTTPDATA command (the first parameter is the length of the payload)
- wait for the board to send you the command DOWNLOAD
- Send the body of the request, which is formatted as a JSON object. This means you have to send something like `{ "latitude" : 12.345, "longitude": 98.765 }`

After all, it is much faster to use a library already developed for this, for instance [ArduinoSIM800L](https://github.com/carrascoacd/ArduinoSIM800L) (check a library available for your GPRS modem, or modify this one)

Comment: Seperating the values in individual print commands was the trick. Thanks!